# How to send a file directly to the printer without using window.print() in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, printing

I need to print a pdf file directly without showing print preview. When i am using

> window.print()
>   it goes to windows print preview page. But i need to send the file directly to the printer without showing print preview page

Comment: Could you give us one solid reason why you dont want to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Thats not possible with pure javascript and html. You'll need to use [silverlight 5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671023(v=VS.95).aspx) (Signed), [flash](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8fa63-8000.html) or [qz-print - js wrapper which uses java](https://github.com/qzind/qz-print).

For i.e. specific solution following may work

[javascript print without print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box)

I have personally implemented only silverlight 5 (Signed), I have not my self implemented flash and qz-print.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your support sir. But i need to implement above feature in PHP

Comment: Then I'll wish you luck my friend! I am 100% sure pure html and js won't cut it. You'll need to add some native component. You can write a browser add-on if its not a public site. Anyways! Best of luck my friend.

Comment: If any success on this achieve in php means please share the code, I'm looking for this code now. Please help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will not allow that to happen. You can use the below plugin to provide beautiful previews.

https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin

Demo: http://etimbo.github.io/jquery-print-preview-plugin/example/index.html