# Any way to print a page directly without dialogue box

Tags: c#

I have a web application QA, I want to print a result page without viewing dialogue box , is there any way,through code or add on

Comment: What have you tried so far? Code and stuff? I am sorry you need to actually work on it a bit before seeking help.

Comment: A quick search on StackOverflow gave multiple hits for questions and answers related to this. Have you tried any of those solutions? Where exactly are you stuck / having trouble?

Comment: You think it should be possible for any random web page to spontaneously send something to a users printer without them being able to prevent it? Pause for a moment, ponder a world in which such a feature exists, and then ask yourself again if you think it should exist.

Comment: I have googled around,I came to know that if we set firefox to some default setting then we can made it

Answer (score 0):

is it possible using Javascript .

Please refer below link.

[[javascript print without print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box])