# How to print directly in IE 11 with ActiveX

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, printing, activex

On the page i show a pdf document in iframe and i try to print it directly. At end of my search, this situation is suitable for IE 11 for the reason security etc. but how can i do that? I don't know. please save me this situation :/

I use these DOM element and function

```
<button type="button" onclick="printDoc()" class="btn success">Print It</button>

<script type="text/javascript">  
                        function printDoc() {
                           $(document).ready(function () {
                         document.getElementById("myDiv").contentWindow.print({
                                    bUI: false, bSilent: true,
                                    bShrinkToFit: true
                                });
                           });
                       };
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript print without print dialog box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveX control does not work on IE11 as Microsoft no longer allows ActiveX plugins to run in its browser space.However if you are having 54 bit operating system you can try by forcing IE to run in 32-bit mode by adding the registry key as given below -

change the registry entry here:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth or
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth

Set it to something greater than 0 and restart IE11

Comment: So IE8 or IE9 have same conditions?

Comment: On IE8 and IE9 you can try to enable ActiveX using this link -
https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/remote-control-enable-activex.html

Comment: Thank you for your sharing :)

Comment: What exactly you want to do, to print in IE11 or in IE8 or in IE9? Is this answer useful for you?

Comment: Actually version isn't important to me. Only i should print it. Now i use ie9 but Activex is enable if you setup your ie  compability setting is on. I try this one but still dialog was shown. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228701/4582992

Comment: so you want to print pdf without print dialogue box?

Comment: Yes exactly but fistly i searched some data on the internet.

Comment: Please edit my answer or post your and marked it as answer. :)