# How to direct Print in PHP with select default printer from web application?

Tags: php, printing

I develop a web based label print application. So Now need to print this automatic without browser print preview. so how can I do this with php direct print...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript print without print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box)

Comment: You should you Javascript for this action

Comment: Ok, have you tried anything to solve your problem? Can we see your code? Or do you expect others to code this for you?

Comment: Current time I implement this with javascript print system with kiosk-printing. so now browser print preview show for just 1 second and take some time to start print. but my client want to direct silent print . I develop my application with php. So how is possible to print direct with php? I think you understand my problem Kerbholz suman Dey and mulquin

Answer (score 1):

## PHP is server side language can't access to client OS drivers (such as printer and etc)

,
 Also you can access & request to run PHP file       scripts only from browser by domain or use cron job(cron is a Linux      utility which schedules a command or script on your server to run       automatically),  you can't access to client system and use printer       driver, but, for this you must use APP that installed on client OS,
or 
automatically run a js script, if client OS is linux: use cron job , if client OS is windows: use       Cron Task or Scheduled Tasks

Answer (score 1):

you can print directly to any printer using PHP.
I am using PHP for printing.

you can use [mike42 escpos github](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) plugin.

after download you need to make a connector for your printer.
use [this](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php#using-a-printconnector)

after you can print.
my sample for a shared printer and for a php file that is running by schedule task is:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;


$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("smb://computername/printername");
$printer = new Printer($connector);

$printer -> text("hello world");
$printer -> text("\n");
$printer -> text("\n");
$printer -> text("hello again");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use webclient for php
refference link https://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/php/
i think this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome,  right click the shortcut icon, edit the target and add
--kiosk-printing  , it does the magic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).