# Epson Tm-30 epos Printing using javascript Issue with connection timeout in web app

Tags: javascript, epson, epos

We are using epos `JavaScript 2.9.0` to connect and print receipts via our webapp from Android devices. But we are getting only `connection_timeout` error all the time. Sometimes though it works and is very unstable. It works fine from the connected pc .

Here is my **code:**

```
var ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();
ePosDev.connect('IP address', 'PORT', callback_connect);
```

> callback_connect's resultConnect variable always return CONNECTION_TIMEOUT

Comment: Do you try to send the direct print command to your printer from webapp?

Comment: how can i do that. can you please guide me.

Comment: Is there any specific browser in which you want to run the webapp or it's open?

Comment: I have tried for crome & firefox but in both its giving same error

Comment: you can directly print from browser, only issue is, you want the dialog box or not. if not try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box