# How to print a HTML page directly without print dialog box of chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, printing

How to print a HTML page directly without dialog box? Is it possible with JavaScript or any other method?
I have already searched everywhere. I have found some solutions on stackoverflow regarding internet explore and activex. But those are outdated.

Please let me know if you have any solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: How is that supposed to work? What about people that have access to several printers? Or no printer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript print without print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box)

Comment: For an example, 
A POS system is using only one printer as the default printer. So any method to set a default printer to print directly without dialog box?

Comment: Please do a little searching before asking. Thank you.

Comment: @Heretic, Already searched several days for a solution. I also found that question you commented. That method doesn't work. Just check that question. Others said doesn't work.